# Unable to use two-way databinding with ObservableField<String>

Tags: android, android-databinding

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <import type="android.databinding.ObservableField"/>

    <variable
        name="message"
        type="ObservableField&lt;String&gt;"/>


</data>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        app:elevation="4dp" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/send"
                android:background="@drawable/balloon_outgoing_normal"
                android:padding="4dp">


                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@={message.get()}"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/audio"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/audio" />


                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/audio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/camera"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/camera"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_white_24dp"
                    android:tint="@color/iconDefault"
                    android:visibility="@{message.get().length()==0?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}" />


                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/camera"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_black_24dp"
                    android:tint="@color/iconDefault"
                    android:visibility="@{message.get().length()==0?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}" />


            </RelativeLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:fabSize="normal" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Where the two-way part is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@={message.get()}"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/audio"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/audio" />
```

and this is the stacktrace:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details.
  cannot generate view binders java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.MethodCallExpr.generateCode(MethodCallExpr.java:72)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.toFullCode(Expr.java:745)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.assertIsInvertible(Expr.java:767)
    at android.databinding.tool.BindingTarget.addInverseBinding(BindingTarget.java:68)
    at android.databinding.tool.LayoutBinder.(LayoutBinder.java:229)
    at android.databinding.tool.DataBinder.(DataBinder.java:52)
    at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.ensureDataBinder(CompilerChef.java:86)
    at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.sealModels(CompilerChef.java:200)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.writeResourceBundle(ProcessExpressions.java:149)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:82)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:154)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:139)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:66)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:93)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I don't use two-way databinding replacing `android:text="@={message.get()}"` with `android:text="@{message.get()}"` everything works fine. So what is the correct way?

Comment: Do you have a setter for your `message`?

Comment: @Amylinn "message" is an ObservableField<String> it should be already handled like ObservableBoolean, ObservableInt... (which works with two-way databinding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `ObservableField` - which works slightly different than the inbuilt `ObservableBoolean` or `ObservableInt`.

With `message.get()` you are only getting a the `String` stored in the `ObservableField`, the `DataBinding` does not know how to store the entered data in it. Following the [example](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-observability-9de4ff3fe038#.929uq7s8t) from George Mount (developer of the DataBinding library), you should do the following:

1. Create a `public final ObservableField<String>` in your class. The class can be a simple Java class, your activity or fragment where you are in.
2. Pass a reference to the class to your `xml`.
3. Use `android:text="@{myClass.myField}"`

Full example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final ObservableField<String> message = new ObservableField<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        message.set("Hello"); //initial data
    }
}
```

And the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="myClass"
            type="com.example.yourpackage.test.MainActivity"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout      
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={myClass.message}" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

You could also wrap your `Fields` with an extra class to keep your `MainActivity` clean.

Comment: My mistake was thinking that ObservableFields and ObservableBoolean work in the same way, unfortunatelly the only way to make it works is yours (by adding the activity as variable)

Comment: I tried it myself before writing this ;) I usually use a kind of a MVVM pattern, where I store necessary variables in my `ViewModel`, which works quite well.

Comment: If you are interested in this topic, I recommend digging through [android-architecture](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) examples.